# Why I can't close my windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce

I tried to close my application running in Windows CE 6.0 device. 
I tried below codes.

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "/r");//to restart
        Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-s");

        Application.Exit();

        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();

        Process procs = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        procs.Kill();

        this.Close();
```

All the above code was working while debugging and application was closed when it executes `Application.Exit();`. But when I compiled my code into **autorun.exe**(executable) and ran, screen freezes while executing the same line.

Please guide me on this issue.

```
  public Form1()
    {
        int i = AddFontResource("\\Flash Disk\\Arial Unicode MS.TTF");
        int c = AddFontResource("\\Flash Disk\\Devanagari_new.TTF");
        int d = AddFontResource("\\Flash Disk\\Mangal.TTF");
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us how you instantiate your main form and any other forms that you may use.  It might give us an insight on what's happening that's causing the hang.  Also, could you tell us what .NET framework you're using with this?  I can think of a couple of bugs and memory leak issues, but I would need more information.

Comment: @Noobacode there is only one form i used to handle multiple screen activities.

Comment: Can you share the instantiation code of that form and tell me what .NET framework you're using?  Are you setting Font by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug that causes hang if you set fonts with your setup.  Comment out your font-setting code and see if it runs and shuts down properly. If it does, then it's the bug with the setting of the font.  Make sure that your target system has the font, by the way... it could be one of the issues.

Get [Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx) and use it to analyze what's causing the hang during the shut down.  It's fairly straightforward to use.  Or this [Debugger](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/win_ce/index.shtml).  I don't know your full setup.

If you're not sure, [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205617/Debugging-Managed-Applications-in-Windows-CE-Devic) will be a very good guide to get your started on debugging.

Also, wrap your code into [`__try{}__except{}`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms924251.aspx), if you haven't done so already.  There could be a memory leak, but we won't know until we see some information from one of those sources.

Comment: @user2865487 with all font-setting code commented out?

Comment: @user2865487 Check my answer for some tips to figure this out.

Comment: @user2865487 Well, it didn't seem like it from your original post.  Except `this.Close()`, everything else causes a shutdown of the application.

Comment: will you tell me how to restart the app when i click the button.

Comment: @user2865487 You would have to setup `CeRunAppAtTime` for it (maybe 15-20 seconds) and then shut it down. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms913957.aspx  So, you're basically scheduling OS to start up your app at a certain time.

Comment: could you take team viewer and check.

Comment: @user2865487 Sorry, I've already devoted too much time.  I'm studying my macroeconomics right now (20 pages to go and it's 11:37 PM).

Comment: let me know when you are free.. i need your help.(rmshbbu@gmail.com)